# How can I delete a row with a specific value of a column from csv ( for example delete all rows with BB or BF columns)

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns, rows

How can I delete a row with a specific value of a column from csv .. I want to delete all BB and BF rows

[image: 1]

I tried this code but it's not working.

I tried this code but it's not working.

```
import csv

f = open('/content/drive/MyDrive/FemaleTrain.csv', encoding='latin-1')

exclude = set(('BB', 'BF'))

reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
for row in reader:
  if any(val in exclude for val in row):
    continue
  else:
    print(row)
```

Comment: can you provide in a reproducible format

Comment: meanwhile, you might wanna look at pandas dataframes

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Does it give an error message, or unexpected output, or what? And if it is unexpected output, please present some sample input as text, not a picture (you don't really expect us to retype that data to reproduce your problem, now do you?), together with the output you get and what you expect instead.

Comment: @lsr729
 it's still the same thing :(

Comment: What error were you getting with the code above... I've run your code with a sample CSV (no Arabic text) and it did what you'd expect: remove and row with `BB` or `BF`, and print everything else.

Comment: But in Arabic it's not working.. It's not giving me Arabic texts anymore

Comment: I have shared two screenshot in the answer below to show u what I am getting as an error when not using encoding= 'unicode_escape').. N when I use it Arabic texts get ruined  here:
ibb.co/JqDgxf4 and ibb.co/WtPyc5x –

Answer (score 0):

Import the file using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", encoding= 'unicode_escape')

#Then use iloc to select the column you want work on (in your case it seems 1st columns)

new_df = df[(df.iloc[:, 0]!="BB") & (df.iloc[:, 0]!="BF")]

print(new_df)
```

Comment: it's giving me an error return codecs.utf_8_decode(input, errors, True) UnicodeDecodeError:
 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 10: invalid continuation byte  and when i use encoding='latin-1' it's messing the language it's reading

Comment: Try to put   encoding= 'unicode_escape'  in read_csv (edited the answer)

Comment: it's not printing the correct language ..

Comment: @avery Then your file is not the encoding that the answer expects.

Comment: Are you able to read the csv file?

Comment: @avery make sure that your csv file does not have any special characters like signs %@#.. etc.

Comment: Can you check what is that in your file at position 10 (as shown in the error)?

Comment: Do you see any unusual data in your CSV file? I cannot tell much without seeing the file. Can you upload it somewhere?

Comment: https://ibb.co/JqDgxf4   and  https://ibb.co/WtPyc5x

Comment: Try adding this `engine='python'` to your read_csv command

Comment: Also, use `delimiter = ";"` not comma

Comment: Still the same problem the Arabic texts get messed up